# Suggestions for improving a probability and statistics cheat sheet

Tags: teaching

#### Context:

In an effort to structure the center pieces that I have came across in probability theory and statics, I created a reference document focussing on the mathematical essentials (available [here](https://github.com/mavam/stat-cookbook)).

By sharing this document, I hope to give statistics students a comprehensive summary of the core material taught in graduate courses about these topics. While mainly intended as a teaching resource, folks might also find it helpful as a personal reference, e.g., to look up distribution relationships or illustrations of common PDFs. I also maintain a 
[page](http://matthias.vallentin.net/probability-and-statistics-cookbook/) with updates and fixes. Feedback is always much appreciated.

#### Question:

- What are your favorite statistics cheat sheets, references, or cookbooks that I could use for inspiration?
- What helped you to structure your knowledge in this domain?
- In the long term, my plan is to enrich this document (or create a separate one) with R examples  to bridge the gap between theory and practice. Would you deem this a valuable extension?

Answer (score 6):

[Tom Short's R Reference Card](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf) is excellent.

Comment: That's indeed a great reference and will be helpful when extending the cheat sheet with R examples.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite is the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) by Patrick Burns.

Comment: This is a nice read. Thus far I have not yet considered Dante but perhaps renaming the cheat sheet to "The Statistics Purgatorio" comes to mind ;-).